# How do I cut up string using a delimiter (space) just like substr in php?

Tags: c, char, substring, delimiter, substr

This is my `Mystr` value:

> others:0.01 penalty:0.02 pdi:0.03 pdp:0.04 interest:0.05
>   principal:0.06 cbu:0.07 savings:0.08 bankcharge:0.09 grt:0.10

My desired output:

> others:0.01
>
> penalty:0.02
>
> pdi:0.03
>
> pdp:0.04
>
> interest:0.05
>
> principal:0.06
>
> cbu:0.07
>
> savings:0.08
>
> bankcharge:0.09
>
> grt:0.10

I want this to be assigned to a different variable. How do I do this?

Comment: You're looking for `strtok` or `strsep`. `strsep` is better, but not portable.

Answer (score 3):

The tool in C for this is `strtok`([GNU Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html), [SUS V2 Spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtok.html)). You call `strtok` the first time with your string and delimiter set. Then, for subsequent portions, call `strtok` with NULL and the delimiter set and it will keep searching from where it left off.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char x[] = "others:0.01 penalty:0.02 pdi:0.03 pdp:0.04 interest:0.05 principal:0.06 cbu:0.07 savings:0.08 bankcharge:0.09 grt:0.10";
    char toPrint[sizeof(x) * 2];
    char *a;

    strcpy(toPrint,strtok(x," "));
    strcat(toPrint,"\n");

    while ((a=strtok(NULL," ")) != NULL) {
        strcat(toPrint,a);
        strcat(toPrint,"\n");
    }
    fputs(toPrint,stdout);
}
```

Prints

```
others:0.01
penalty:0.02
pdi:0.03
pdp:0.04
interest:0.05
principal:0.06
cbu:0.07
savings:0.08
bankcharge:0.09
grt:0.10
```

Note that `strtok` modifies the original array. At the end of the program, the `x` array contains `"1\02\03\04"`. All the delimiters have been overwritten by zeros. Also note that two consecutive delimiters in the string will cause `strtok` to yield an empty string `""` for the (missing) value.

Comment: Could be nice with a link as reference and perhaps a user example=)

Comment: thank you for the answer.. i just know now that their is a function just like substr in php.. Good day and a bless day..

Comment: Understood. Making a collection of the substrings in C would be 2 or 3 more 'cans of worms'! :)

Comment: by the way how can i assign each string being cut using strtok..

int main() {
char str[] = "penalty:0.01 pdi:0.02 pdp:0.03";

char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;

}

Comment: That's the *can of worms* I mentioned. It's a lot of work. The simplest way is to have an array of pointers and you save the pointers in the array. It gets tricky if you can't predict the maximum size of the array and need to `realloc` to get more space. Another option is a linked-list.

Comment: i want to assign thus value in different variable just like:

a = penalty:0.01

b = pdi:0.02

c = pdp:0.03

so that i cant strcat it to the value toPrint like

strcat(toPrint, a);

strcat(toPrint, "\n");

strcat(toPrint, b);

Thank you for the help..

Comment: That should work fine. But you don't need the variable. `strcat(toPrint,strtok(NULL," "))`. Or `sprintf(toPrint,"%s\n",strtok(NULL," "))`. Make sure `toPrint` is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you were writing code by Python, you would be lucky to use split().
In C, you can use strtok http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/